# Field name can not contain colon in mapping using Azure Data Factory to convert AWS S3 .csv to CosmosDb

Tags: azure, mapping, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use Azure Data Factory to convert CSV data from an Amazon S3 bucket into JSON Document (collection) in CosmosDB. I get the error in the title - Field name can not contain colon in mapping - despite me having no colon that I can find in any of my column names, source or destination. Please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when any name in column mapping contains colon.

Could you click the 'Code' button on the top right corner of the pipeline edit canvas, and check proproties -> activities -> typeProperties -> translator -> columnMappings, if there is any colon in key or value under it?

Answer (score 0):

I find a colon in 'PostCode:' of the sink column. BTW, the validation for column mapping names will be removed in the next few weeks. For now you need to rename it to bypass the validation.